# Node-red SQL output object / Array conversion

Tags: json, node.js, node-red

I'm doing a SQL query in Node-Red to output a load of time/value data. This data is then passed to a web page for display in a graph.

Previously I've used php to do the SQL query, which I'm trying to replace. However SQL queries in php are delivered in a different format.

With Node-Red, I get:

```
[
  {
    "Watts": 1018,
    "Time": 1453825454
  },
  {
    "Watts": 1018,
    "Time": 1453825448
  },
  {
    "Watts": 1010,
    "Time": 1453825442
  }]
```

With PHP, I get:

```
[
   [1453819620000,962],
   [1453819614000,950],
   [1453819608000,967],
   [1453819602000,947]
]
```

I think I'm getting an array from php and an array of JSON objects from Node-Red. How do I convert the Node-Red object to be output from Node-Red in the same format as the PHP is? (Ie: I want to handle the processing at the server, rather than the client.)

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking here. Do you want to know how to convert the Node-RED format into the PHP format?

Comment: I forgot to say - this is so that I can take output from Node-red and put it directly into a flot graph.

Answer (score 0):

A function node can be used to generate something in the same format.

```
var array = msg.payload;
var phpFormat = "[";

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
 phpFormat += "[" + 
   // time format differ, NodeJS is in seconds
   // php is in milliseconds
   (array[i].Time * 1000 ) + 
   "," + 
   array[i].Watts + "],";

}

//take the last "," off
phpFormat = phpFormat.substring(0,phpFormat.lenght - 1);
phpFormat += "]";

msg.payload = phpFormat;

return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a bit of help from a chap at work and here is what he's come up with, modified for node-red by me:

```
var outputArray = [];

for(var i in msg.payload){
    var entryData = [msg.payload[i]['Time']];
    for(var attr in msg.payload[i]) {
        if(attr!='Time') {
            entryData.push(msg.payload[i][attr])}
            };
    outputArray.push(entryData); } 

var returnMsg={"payload":outputArray};
return returnMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, I know, this question is over 2 years old... however, for the *next* 500 people seeking an answer to a similar problem, I'd like to highlight the new JSONata expression feature built-in to the `change` node. Using this simple expression:

```
payload.[Time, Watts]
```

transforms your JS objects into the requested output of an array of arrays. In fact, much of my old repetitive looping through arrays has been replaced with some simpler (to me) expressions like this.

The magic of the lambda syntax evaluator is documented on the [JSONata site](http://jsonata.org). There you will also find the [online exerciser](http://try.jsonata.org) where you can build an expression against your own data and immediately see the resulting structure.

> Note: in order to use a jsonata expression in your change node, be sure to select the `J:` pulldown next to the input field (not the `{}` JSON option)... two *totally* different things!